# How to verify validion of form inside form?

Tags: html, typescript

I'm trying to verify a form that's inside a form.

The idea is to create a user's html page with the option to create a contact list.

My goal is to verify both forms with one click on the 'Save User Profile' button.

My question is How to verify the validion of the inner form inside the main form?

**NO BOOTSTRAP AND OTHERS.**

Main form:

HTML:

```
<div class="container"
 style="width: 60%;">
   <h5>User Profile</h5>
   <div>
          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
                #f=ngForm>
                 <!-- Name -->
                 <div class="column">
                        <label for="name"
                               style="margin-left: 5px;">Name</label><br>
                        <input type="text"
                               [(ngModel)]="user.name"
                               name="name"
                               id="name"
                               required
                               minlength="2"
                               maxlength="30"
                               #n="ngModel">
                        <p *ngIf="!n.valid && n.touched"
                           style="color: red;"> Please insert a name with 2-30 chars</p>
                 </div>

                 <!-- Organization -->
                 <div class="column">
                        <label for="orga"
                               style="margin-left: 5px;">Organization</label><br>
                        <input type="text"
                               [(ngModel)]="user.organization"
                               name="orga"
                               id="orga">
                 </div>
                 <br><br><br><br><br>
                 <h5>Contact Information</h5>
                 <div class="box">
                        <app-user-card *ngFor="let c of contacts; let i = index"
                                       [id]="i"
                                       [user]="user"></app-user-card>
                        <br><br>

                 </div>
                 <button type="button"
                         class="btn-add"
                         (click)="addContact()">Add Contact</button>
                 <button class="btn-save"
                         type="submit"
                         [disabled]="!f.valid">Save User Profile
                 </button>
          </form>
   </div>
```

TS:

```
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit {
users: User[] = []
user: User = {
name: '',
organization: '',
contacts: []
}

id: number
contacts: Contact[] = []
contact: Contact = {
id: 0,
type: '',
label: '',
contact: ''
}


constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.user.contacts = this.contacts
}


addContact() {
this.contacts.push(new Contact(this.id, this.contact.type, this.contact.label, this.contact.contact))
}

onSubmit() {
/* Upgrade option:  Check if a user exists on the system and view his contacts*/
this.users.push(new User(this.user.name, this.user.organization, this.contacts))
console.log(this.users);
 }
}
```

inner form:

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
   <form #f = "ngForm">
          <div class="column">
                 <label for="contactType">Type of Contact</label><br>
                 <select id="contactType"
                         [(ngModel)]=contact.type
                         name="cotactType"
                         style="width: 95%;"
                         required>
                        <option value="email">Email</option>
                        <option value="phone">Phone</option>
                 </select>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
                 <label for="label">Contact Label</label><br>
                 <input type="text"
                        [(ngModel)]="contact.label"
                        id="label"
                        name="lable"
                        style="width: 95%;"
                        required
                        minlength="2"
                        maxlength="20"
                        #l>
                 <p *ngIf="!l.valid && l.touched"
                    style="color: red;">Label is required!</p>
          </div>
          <div>
                 <label for="contact"
                        style="margin-left: 5px;">Email/Phon No.</label><br>
                 <input type="text"
                        [(ngModel)]=contact.contact
                        required
                        id="contact"
                        name="contact"
                        style="width: 98%;"
                        #c>
                 <p *ngIf="!c.valid && c.touched"
                    style="color: red;">Email/Phon No is required!</p>
          </div>
          <button type="button"
                  class="btn-remove"
                  style="left: 69%;position: relative;">Remove</button>
   </form>
```

TS:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-user-card',
templateUrl: './user-card.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./user-card.component.css']
})
export class UserCardComponent implements OnInit {
contact: Contact = {
id: 0,
type: '',
label: '',
contact: ''
}

@ViewChild("f") contactDetails: NgForm

@Input() id: number

constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question - isn't a captcha system good enough? Or do you want something different?

Comment: When I press the button "Save User Profile", Only the main page form is checked , And what's shown by the loop hasn't been checked